# Store search language?

Tags: 8.0, store

It seems the store app will only search in my local language. When an app happens to have a german translation, and I search for its english title, it is not found! Can I change this *without changing the phone language* (or country or whatnot)?

- The phone language is german. (I bought in in germany)
- The MS account language is also german (or so I assume, since all options I set there are german.)

Comment: Can you edit the question providing you Microsoft account language and your phone language+region options?

Comment: If your phone set to German? Is your Microsoft account set up as German?

Comment: @MartinBa what is you se the **Country** of your phone to the United States? Under **Settings**.

Comment: @Mikael - the whole point of the question is to search for english apps *without* messing with the phone settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to visit [the U.S. Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/) via a browser.

Another way is to download a third-party Store browser like [WPstore](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=cacb843f-ee0e-403a-be4d-2dd8ef82d2a2).